# Matlab PDE Solver Issue

Tags: matlab

Im trying to solve the transient heat equation in 1D and comparing the analytical and numerial solutions. The solutions have the same trend but are very different, also the relative error is coming out to be zero, even though its clearly not supposed to be. Im not sure if I have solved the PDE correctly. (the pde is du/dt = d^2u/dx^2) and bcs are u(0,t)=1, u(100,t) = 0, u(x,0)=0. Can someone please take a look at my code?

```
    function he
m = 0;
x = linspace(0,100,500);
t = linspace(0,1000,500);
sol = pdepe(m,@hepde,@heic,@hebc,x,t);
u = sol(:,:,1);
y = erfc(x./(2*(t.^0.5)));
r=(y-u(70,:))/y;
figure;
plot(x,u(50,:),'.',x,u(150,:),'.',x,u(250,:),'.',x,u(end,:),'.',x,y,'.');
title('Numerical Solutions at different times.');
legend('t=100','t=300','t=500','t=700','y ana',0);
xlabel('Distance x');
ylabel('u(x,t)');
figure;
plot(x,r);
title('error in numerical and analytical solution');
legend('error',0);
xlabel('Distance x');
ylabel('error');

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
function [c,f,s] = hepde(x,t,u,DuDx)
c = 1;
f = DuDx;
s = 0;
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
function u0 = heic(x)
u0 = 0;
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = hebc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t)
pl = ul-1;
ql = 0;
pr = ur;
qr = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually had the solution all set up correctly, you just used the results incorrectly. I'll go through the errors one by one.

```
sol = pdepe(m,@hepde,@heic,@hebc,x,t);
u = sol(:,:,1);
```

You found the right answer, but the line `u=sol(:,:,1);` is useless as `size(sol)=[2 2]`, so you may as well just do `u=pdepe(...);`.

Now when you calculated your exact solution you did it very strangely. You want to find it at each `x`/`t` combination, but you did it only at some of them. You need to use `meshgrid` to get all the combinations of `x` and `t` then calculate your exact solution at each one.

```
[X,T]=meshgrid(x,t);
y = erfc(X./(2*(T.^0.5)));
```

Then you need to calculate the error differently.

```
r=(y-u)./y;
figure(3);
```

And plot differently.

```
plot(x,u(50,:),'b',x,u(150,:),'g',x,u(250,:),'r',x,u(end,:),'c',x,y(50,:),'b--',x,y(150,:),'g--',x,y(250,:),'r--',x,y(end,:),'c--');
```

Actually your exact solution doesn't satisfy the boundary condition at `x=100`......